# SSIS Package Runs from Catalog, not from SQL Server Agent (Same User)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-agent

I have a SSIS package, developed for SQL Server 2012, that uses a script component to open an Excel workbook and execute a macro.  This package runs in visual studio, and I am able to deploy to SQL Server 2012.

In SQL Server, I am able to execute the package by selecting it from the Integration Services Catalogs and Right Click --> Execute... (with 32-bit runtime).  I understand that this executes the package as the user that I am logged in to the server as.  The package executes successfully in this scenario.

When I create a SQL Server Agent job to execute the package nightly, I have created a proxy user with the same domain user that I used to log into the SQL server it fails with the following error:

> The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80070002 (Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.). The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.

I have ensured that the SQL Server Agent job is also using the 32-bit runtime.  Since the proxy user is also the user that I logged into the SQL Server with, I do not believe it is a permissions issue (at least for that user).

Does SQL Server Agent have other permissions that need to be granted?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving read/write permissions to the SQL Database Engine Service account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$<Instance Name>` *(Where `<Instance Name>` should be replaced by the installed instance name)*:

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SSIS - Problems while executing package from SQL Server Agent Job](https://data-dev.blogspot.com/2019/07/ssis-problems-while-executing-package.html)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, unfortunately this does not seem to have fixed it.  Still with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue was with the service account attempting to open Excel.  I updated the DCOM to use a specified user to open excel, [based on this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ef3ea81-ed4c-4327-ba1a-2c03a76886ac/ssis-package-runs-ok-manually-but-not-as-a-scheduled-job-error-message-quotexception-has-been?forum=sqlintegrationservices), and the job will now run via SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 0):

I found that:

Enter "Job step properties"

There enter "Configuration" -> "Advanced"

and check "32-bit runtime"

Solved my issue.