# SSIS Package failing when excecuted by a SQL Job

Tags: sql, ssis, package, sql-server-agent

I have a SSIS package that works great on its own, and even when I execute the package on SSMS.  The problem comes in when I set it up as a job.  Here is what the error message is, and of course any help would be much appreciated:

[image]

Comment: See hyperlink above..

Comment: Duplicate of this I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186227/ssis-package-runs-from-catalog-not-from-sql-server-agent-same-user

Comment: The error messages give you the information you need. It is one of two issues. Either the id the job is running under does not have the proper permission to the directory or the server cannot find the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change the access rights to rwxrwxrwx for your destination file

```
CustMaster.csv needs access rights
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me is:

Enter "Job step properties"

There enter "Configuration" -> "Advanced"

and check "32-bit runtime"

Solved my issue.